# Jquery selector for elements inside siblings divs

Tags: jquery

So I have these two div with select tag.

```js
$('.selectedMediaType').change(function() {
  if ($(this).val() === 'video') {
    $(this).find('.videoDetails').html('some options will be added here');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-sm-2">
  <select name="form-0-type" class="selectedMediaType">
    <option value="video">video</option>
    <option value="audio">audio</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-3">
  <select name="form-0-resolution" class="videoDetails"></select>
</div>
```

So the idea is that, if the value of first select change then I will dynamically add options for the second select tag. However, this is not working. How can I select the first `videoDetails` on value change of `selectedMediaType`.

Answer (score 1):

You're searching within the select for `.videoDetails`. You need to find your scope. For example

```
$(this).closest('.div').next('div').find('.videoDetails').html('some options will be added here');
```

Although I'd make it more specific by adding attributes, in case the dom changes.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of issues. You were searching inside of `selectedMediaType` to find the other drop-down. Obviously, it didn't find it.

Also, you need to add options as in my demo.

```js
$('.selectedMediaType').change(function() 
{
    var $videoDetails = $('.videoDetails');
    $videoDetails.empty();
    switch( $(this).val() )
    {
      case 'audio' :
        $videoDetails.append( $("<option />").attr("value", 1).html("Cat") );
        $videoDetails.append( $("<option />").attr("value", 2).html("Dog") );
      break;

      case 'video' :
        $videoDetails.append( $("<option />").attr("value", 1).html("One") );
        $videoDetails.append( $("<option />").attr("value", 2).html("Two") );
      break;
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-sm-2">
  <select name="form-0-type" class="selectedMediaType">
    <option value="video">video</option>
    <option value="audio">audio</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-3">
  <select name="form-0-resolution" class="videoDetails"></select>
</div>
```